# Google Play services resources were not found. 'AdsMob'

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, preferenceactivity, interstitial

I am getting this error when I try to load and InterstitialAd from google AdMob. I know that I have written the code correctly. As I followed the short tutorial on https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#play

All the happens is I get and error in the Logcat. What might I be doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
public class Pref extends PreferenceActivity implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    /** The view to show the ad. */
      private AdView adView;

      /* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
      private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "MY_ID";
      private static final String inAD_UNIT_ID = "MY_ID";
      private InterstitialAd interstitial;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.ad_layout);


        //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        //getPreferenceManager()
                //.setSharedPreferencesName("com.gordondev.south_korea");
        //addPreferencesFromResource(2130903040);
        //getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
            //  .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(inAD_UNIT_ID);

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adview);
        layout.addView(adView);

        //((LinearLayout)view).addView(adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
            .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest1);


    }

    // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
      public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
      }
```

Here is the Logcat error:

```
03-13 16:49:41.565: I/Ads(29755): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("099098AA8954CC0C01AD412143D81BDD") to get test ads on this device.
03-13 16:49:41.565: I/Ads(29755): Starting ad request.
03-13 16:49:41.575: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(29755): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-13 16:49:41.575: I/Ads(29755): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("099098AA8954CC0C01AD412143D81BDD") to get test ads on this device.
03-13 16:49:41.575: I/Ads(29755): Starting ad request.
03-13 16:49:41.585: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(29755): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-13 16:49:41.625: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(29755): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-13 16:49:41.635: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(29755): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-13 16:49:41.645: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(29755): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-13 16:49:41.645: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(29755): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-13 16:49:42.365: I/Ads(29755): Ad finished loading.
03-13 16:49:43.085: I/Ads(29755): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
03-13 16:49:43.085: I/Ads(29755): Ad finished loading.
```

Comment: do you have added your id value to the string?

Comment: Yes. I just replaced it for the question.

Comment: Can you @Override the  method onCreate?

Comment: Its not necessary. Activity runs fine without AdMob code. The problem is with the AdMob.

Comment: Does your phone have installed google play services?

Comment: What does that have to do with the code...?

Comment: Do I have to have google play on my device to see ad..? I am not sure.

Comment: I do have google play on testing device.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error running my apps on my device. It seems that the problem have to do with your device.Try using your app to another device

If the ads will appear, your code seems to be fine.

Also you can change this line to this:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

Make sure that you have the correct **google play libraries** in your project

[image]

If you have done these : https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/
Your app  ads should work perfectly

Comment: I just tried the google example and it runs fine on my device.

Answer (score 1):

```
03-13 16:49:41.585: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(29755): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

is a benign error. If the ads are showing don't worry about it.
Your code looks fine.