# Why Google sample BannerExample does not work with Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ads, banner

I try to run the Google sample named BannerExample but the banner is not displayed.
You can find the project code source here : [bannerexample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples)
I just change the variables : 
INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE by the value given in the Admob interface. 
and INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE by the value given by the SDK when it is launched.

My BannerExample.java:

```
package com.google.example.gms.ads.banner;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} that embeds an AdView.
 */
public class BannerSample extends Activity {
  /** The view to show the ad. */
  private AdView adView;

  /* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
  private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-55043114705XXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("653B45F6B15FB941FED6F87440C626BE")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.resume();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
  }

  /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

But when I launch the application I an empty activity with title "BannerAdsSample" and below the "HelloWorlds!" that's all.

And my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.google.example.gms.ads.banner"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
              android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity android:name=".BannerSample"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>



</manifest>
```

So in the logs I have this issue :

```
07-22 00:46:50.254: W/ApplicationPackageManager(2509): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-22 00:46:50.254: I/PersonaManager(2509): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
07-22 00:46:50.314: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(2509): Parent view is not a TextView
07-22 00:46:50.384: D/dalvikvm(2509): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-579524131.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
07-22 00:46:50.394: I/Ads(2509): Starting ad request.
07-22 00:46:50.404: I/Ads(2509): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
07-22 00:46:50.404: V/WebViewChromium(2509): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {42aad368}
07-22 00:46:50.404: I/chromium(2509): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
07-22 00:46:50.414: I/BrowserProcessMain(2509): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
07-22 00:46:50.414: W/chromium(2509): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
07-22 00:46:50.424: W/ApplicationPackageManager(2509): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-22 00:46:50.424: I/Adreno-EGL(2509): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
07-22 00:46:50.424: I/Adreno-EGL(2509): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
07-22 00:46:50.424: I/Adreno-EGL(2509): Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
07-22 00:46:50.424: I/Adreno-EGL(2509): Local Branch: 
07-22 00:46:50.424: I/Adreno-EGL(2509): Remote Branch: 
07-22 00:46:50.424: I/Adreno-EGL(2509): Local Patches: 
07-22 00:46:50.424: I/Adreno-EGL(2509): Reconstruct Branch: 
07-22 00:46:50.514: D/dalvikvm(2509): DexOpt: --- END 'ads-579524131.jar' (success) ---
07-22 00:46:50.514: D/dalvikvm(2509): DEX prep '/data/data/com.google.example.gms.ads.banner/cache/ads-579524131.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 122ms
07-22 00:46:50.524: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2509): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
07-22 00:46:50.554: D/OpenGLRenderer(2509): Enabling debug mode 0
07-22 00:46:50.574: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2509): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
07-22 00:46:50.574: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2509): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
07-22 00:46:50.924: W/Ads(2509): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
07-22 00:46:50.934: W/Ads(2509): Failed to load ad: 1
```

and the activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my eclipse settings I have the Google play service lib set as libray so like this :
Properties->Android->Library

Reference:
adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Project:
google-play-service_lib

with the green Arrow. I cannot post image for the moment... I am missing 10 approvals

Project Build Target:

```
TargetName : Android 4.4.2 
Vendor : Android Open Source Project
Platform : 4.4.2 
API Level : 19
```

So what is it wrong if the google play service lib is referenced as library but in the logs it says that is not found ?

I have added 2 new Ad networks accounts: AdFalcon and MobFox.
I have associated to the Google's ad Sample. 
So now I have 3 differents ad provider: AdMob Network (positionnement dynamique), AdFalcon and MobFox in order to use "mediation" as it is sugested in this post :
[AdMod mediation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870961/interstitials-ads-fail-to-load-on-real-test)

But it doesn't change anything... I still have the same problem. 
So now in my logs I have :

```
09-01 19:25:15.501: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16134): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included. 
09-01 19:25:16.052: I/Ads(16134): No fill from ad server. 
09-01 19:25:16.052: W/Ads(16134): Failed to load ad: 3
```

As we can see thanks to this post :
[begin error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390787/google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-adsmob)
the error E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16134): The Google Play ... so not a "true issue"
but the 2 other ones are the last lines writen in the logcat and still nothing in the console logs.

In my Admod account, I have to associate my application name to the application in the Google play Store. But as it is just a poke I did not have to publish the "Google Banner Sample" in play Store no ?
So my application have 3 ad providers and I found an application named "Banner Sample Test" that is I hope the same than me.

So what is the problem ?

May I have to wait 4 days ?! as it is suggested here [wait 4 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382029/admob-test-ads-shows-only-on-english-devices)

So where is the issue ?

Best Regards

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390787/google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-adsmob

Comment: I saw it but I don't have another Android device. I am running it on my Galaxy S4. Everything is fine except this missing ads.

Comment: If you have wifi, then you can check it on emulator too. Or simply install apk in your friends device.

Comment: OK but if it works on another device, how to make it runs on this one ? I will try this evening on emulator.

Comment: Do you have some ideas about options on the device that could be changed in order to fix it ?

Comment: I think, you need to check layout of your ad. There might be  the problem, i guess.

Comment: You mean replace my linearlayout by RelativeLayout or something else ?

Comment: Try to do that. & take one more relative layout at top for your adview.

Comment: I tried the RelativeLayout but it does not change anything.
Another thing very strange is something I have : and something I have :
I/Ads(27563): No fill from ad server.
W/Ads(27563): Failed to load ad: 3
So may be the fact that error change may give you some information.

I have some pb with the emulator it says that application may not be launched due to read-only system (even if I set a valeur for sd card).

Comment: This link gives answer of your last comment : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870961/interstitials-ads-fail-to-load-on-real-test

Comment: Yes I already see that but I never see a ad on the screen. So may be he's true about this but It should works at least one time.

Comment: I have added more ads provider but it doesn't change anything. I have updated my description